# Relative strength of Jones and colored Jones polynomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, knot-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, reshetikhin-turaev, jones-polynomial

this is my first post here.
I've been studying some Knot Theory and I came to a question concerning invariants.

We know that the Jones polynomial is related to the RT-invariant associated to the two-dimensional representation $V_1$ of the quantum group $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$. We also have the notion of colored Jones polynomial, that is related to the other irreducible representations of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$. My question is:
is the $(N+1)$-colored Jones polynomial somehow stronger than the $N$-colored Jones polynomial? Or, in other words: are the invariants that come from higher dimensional representations of $U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ somehow stronger than the ones who comes from lower dimensional representations?
I'm asking this question because I think I have found an example of a pair of knots that share the same Jones Polynomial (or $V_1$ invariant) but have different $V_2$ invariants.
Does this happen in general? Is it possible to find a pair of knots that share the same $V_2$ invariant but have different $V_1$ invariants?

Also, I would appreciate if you could let me know some references on this subject.